# Fraud messages were sent by my Twilio number

Tags: twilio

I am a big fan of Twilio and I love to use Twilio
Since a month ago, some unexpected things occurred on my Twilio account,
Fraud messages were sent by my Twilio number around 4 times so far,
Every time, the fraud happened, Twilio suspended my account to ask me to investigate this fraud,
I tried to find something wrong with me, but I wasn't able to find what is wrong here
I never shared my credentials, but fraud messages were sent by my Twilio number.

Here is a number of things I want to mention

- Only one number was used for each time
- I released the numbers used for fraud when I found the fraud, but another number was used for the fraud again
- 3,000 fraud messages were sent at once
- The fraud messages were related to some other services like Amazon ads, Apple ads, etc.

What I think

- I don't think someone hacked my account and send this fraud message using my Twilio number since only one number is used for this Fraud
- Maybe these numbers are shared by other VoIP services, meaning two services are using one number at the same time

I want to know

- if someone could send messages using my number without auth token and account sid on Twilio?
- if Twilio doesn't know how to prevent this fraud?
- if anyone else has this experience on Twilio?
- what is the best and secure service for SMS, I am considering Telnyx, any idea?

Thanks in advance

Comment: Do you see these fraud messages in your SMS logs for the date/times they were reported? Dif you notice your account balance decreasing during this event?

Comment: Yeah, I can certainly see those fraud messages and Twilio charge those fraud messages from my balance

Comment: If that is the case, then somehow they have access to either your Account SID/Auth Token or your API Keys, https://www.twilio.com/docs/iam/pkcv/account-and-key-management-api-keys. You can rotate your Account SID/Auth Token by following these steps - https://support.twilio.com/hc/en-us/articles/223136027-Auth-Tokens-and-How-to-Change-Them. If you did change your keys and remove the old keys, then try to discover how the keys could be leaking online. Another possibility is a weakness in your application being exploited.

Comment: Whatif the fraud messages were not charged from my balance?

Comment: If the messages weren't in your logs/and you weren't being charged for them, then it could point to the message being spoofed from another provider that doesn't require the verification/ownership of the source phone number.